# Servo motor misbehaves e.g. jumps and glitches

Tags: motor, pwm, circuit-design, servo

I am controlling a digital metal geared servo motor ([MKS-HBL880](http://www.mksservosusa.com/product.php?productid=131)) using TI's C2000 LaunchPadXL TMS320F28379D microcontroller. The servo is powered with a **7.4V 2S-Lipo battery**. The microcontroller and the external battery are common grounded. When the battery is fully charged, the supplied voltage is 8.3V.

The problem is that sometimes the servo motor acts erratically, e.g. jumps between positions and gets stuck during operation. Currently, there's a 1000uF capacitor between the V+ and GND pins. (The datasheet is [here](http://www.vek-online.de/files/4188/upload/Elektrolyt/CD110.pdf).). Using this capacitor reduced the jumps and misbehavior of the motor, but did not fully solve it.

As [Tony Stewart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17574/tony-stewart-older-than-dirt) suggested on a [different question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360072/why-is-my-servo-motor-behaving-erraticly?noredirect=1#comment868289_360072) of mine, the capacitor should be ultra-low ESR. So I decided to order a number of low ESR capacitors with capacitance ranging from 22uF and 1200uF and test which one solves the issue. I found the following options. The full datasheet can be found [here](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDE0000/ABA0000C1184.pdf).

[image: Page from datasheet for Panasonic Aluminium Electrolytic Capacitors]

Can someone clarify if the highlighted capacitors would do the job, is the ESR low enough, and if I am on the right path?

Thank you.

**---- EDIT ----**

Voltage across +V and GND pins of the motor:

https://youtu.be/vTABHKIUKqs

Voltage across 10 Ohm resistor in series with +V pin of the motor:

https://youtu.be/gONaPpY2UEg

[image]

[image]

Note that this result is largely influenced by the choice of \$\Delta t\$.

I introduced a series resistor to the decoupling capacitor, creating a RC circuit and the spikes/dips in the supplied voltage disappeared.

Video: https://youtu.be/1aO6T7MvkCk

Comment: how do you know for sure that this really is the problem?

Comment: @dmb I don't know for sure. I recorded the dips in the supplied voltage during motion. See my edit. At the moment the battery voltage is 7.79V, but when the battery drains out (i.e. the voltage reduces) the dips get larger and the motor starts to behave erratically. Perhaps, a voltage regulator can be considered?

Comment: could it be that the mechanical load spikes suddenly for some reason? maybe try to get a reading for what the current is doing - insert a very small sense resistor and use the scope?

Comment: @dmb Please see my edit I provided a link for a new video. The motion seems to be smoother. I charged the battery between two experiments. The battery voltage was 7.9V during this experiment.

Comment: @johnger my code. The frequency of the PWM signal is 560Hz and the duty cycle is fluctuating between 20.8% and 54% at a frequency of ~2Hz.

Comment: @canberk_gurel what is the pwm pulse waveform?

Comment: @johnger square

Comment: is that your decoupling cap at the end of those long wires? I would try to get it as close to the motor pins as possible.

Comment: (or are those the supply wires to the motor pins?)

Comment: @dmb I know that a decoupling capacitor needs to be as close to the motor as possible. The cable of the motor is 24 cm (9.45 inch) and since it's a female cable I had to add a male-to-male extension (length of 20 cm (7.87402 inch)) and then connected the capacitor. Once I make sure this is the correct capacitance for my task, I will design a PCB. I can try to get rid of the extension, let me know what you think.

Comment: I wanted to ask you about the magnitude of those current pulses that you are seeing across the 10R resistor. The voltage scale is not visible in your video. Maybe you just need a larger cap? You should be able to get a rough guess at the kind of value you need from I = C*dv/dt - you can see how wide the current pulses are, and you have an idea of the current, so calculate the cap to get the voltage spikes down to where you want them. (Then add 20% or so for cap tolerances.)

Comment: @dmb The voltage scale is 2V per division and the time scale is 5ms per division. According to the calculation I added to the post, the capacitance should be around 187.16uF.

Comment: and what size of cap was actually fitted when you made that scope reading? - was it the 1000uF? I would just try doubling or even trebling the capacitance and see if that fixes the problem. You have 2A spikes and that is with a 10R resistor - they can be much worse without it.

Comment: @dmb Yes, it was with 1000uF. The problem solved now. I am using 1000uF capacitor and a series 10R resistor. Please see my final edit. Thank you for the support.

Comment: This is not really a distinct new question; your original existing question remains unresolved, and it's not remotely established (more likely highly doubtful) that a large capacitor is going to solve your problem.  For that matter, even if it would this is dangerously close to a shopping question.

Comment: You do not want a 10 ohm resistor in series with the supply to your motor.  Really, you do not want that - at best it has the effect of turning your very expensive servo into a much weaker, cheaper one.  Put any actual load on it and you'll likely burn your finger or melt anything touching that resistor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't think you watched the video in the other question, if you did you would know that the mentioned issue in that question is solved. The only reason it is not marked as solved is that the solution is in the comments and it is not an answer to the question. This question serves in the purpose of improving the performance that is obtained as a result of the solution suggested in the other question. Do you have any suggestions on how to get rid of the dips without the series resistor? Also what do you mean by "shopping question"?

Comment: You have it all mixed up to the point of backwards: the series resistor doesn't eliminate dips, it *causes* them and makes the word "performance" entirely inapplicable by severely limiting the power available to move the servo's motor.  Get rid of all of this misguided nonsense and identify the cause of the original problem.  Slapping a big capacitor on it is not the answer.